# Punctuation and Footnotes in Mandarin Chinese

Tags: translation, grammar, punctuation

I'm trying to translate a research paper into Mandarin Chinese and I was hoping I could get some insite on proper footnote placement around punctuation. For example， if I'm trying to footnote twice in a sentence, should I place the footnote before or after the standard Chinese periods and commas (i.e. 什么什么，1什么什么。2) or should I place it before the punctuation (i.e. 什么什么1，什么什么2。)?

Furthermore, If I have multiple footnotes, how should they be separated? with a comma, as in English (i.e.什么什么1，2，3 ）? (along those lines, should I use full-sized punctuation in that instance or is western punctuation cleaner (i.e. 什么什么1,2,3?)

I apologize for all of the "什么什么" action in there， its proprietary and I can't share any of the actual content.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numbers in square brackets, before punctuation, separated by "、"

什么什么[1]、[2]。

For more detail, search baidu for 脚注格式.

Comment: Punctuation question answered by Ampersand. TeeHeeHee....